# OpenLayers 4, whenever you zoom with mousewheel fast the map dissapears

Tags: javascript, maps, openlayers, wms

I have a map done with OpenLayers 4.3.2 with a lot of layers, sometimes 10, but only one shows at a time. The initialization of the map object is done like this:

```
var mousePositionControl = new ol.control.MousePosition({
        coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(4),
        projection: 'EPSG:4326',
        className: 'ol-lat-lon',
        target: getElementById('location'),
        undefinedHTML: '&nbsp;'
    });

//This is the control for the scale line at the bottom of t
var scaleLineControl = new ol.control.ScaleLine();

ol3view = new ol.View({
             projection: _map_projection,
             center: defCenter,
             zoom: mapConfig.zoom,
             maxZoom: mapConfig.zoomLevels,
             zoomFactor: mapConfig.zoomFactor,
             maxResolution: mapConfig.maxResolution
             extent: resExtent  // Not working
          });

map = new ol.Map({
    interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({mouseWheelZoom:false})
                  .extend([
                     new ol.interaction.MouseWheelZoom({
          constrainResolution: true,
          duration: 250, timeout: 200
        })
    ]), 
    controls: ol.control.defaults()
              .extend([mousePositionControl, scaleLineControl]),
    overlays: [ol_popup], //Overlay used for popup
    target: 'map', // Define 'div' that contains the map
    renderer: 'canvas', 
    view: ol3view
  });
```

What happens is that whenever i make a zoom with the mousewheel kinda fast the map disappears, it breaks.
The MouseWheelZoom interaction defined is an attempt to see if changing the times of the animation or Mouse wheel timeout of the zoom would stop breaking the map. 
This bug occurs specially with Tiled layers that have streamlines but can be replicated with any layer.

I used to have this same web app done with OpenLayers 3 and this bug never ever happened, so it has definitely something to do with the new OpenLayers version, but I can't find a fix for it. Here is a link to the app I'm currently testing on, where you can replicate the bug: http://pronosticos.unam.mx:8080/MASTEROL4/mapviewer

Comment: It works fine here (Firefox 56), though the zooming is not smooth.

Comment: i have replicated this bug in firefox and chrome. Maybe try changing the layer to a ncWMS one and see what happens ?

Comment: ah, it occurs after changing layer only (reload, change layer, mouse-wheel, bang)

Comment: so the issue is likely located where you change layers, as the mouse-wheel zoom works fine after doing a reload

Comment: At the end did you find a solution?